# Binomial? probability of two producing defective articles machines.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that machine A produces (on a daily basis) twice the articles that machine B produces.

However, 4/100 of the articles produced by machine A are defective while 2/100 of the articles produced by machine B are defective.

We combine the production of this two machines, and we take a sample of size 10 of the combined production.

What is the probability that this sample contains two defective articles?

My reasoning was as follows:

Let's say that $M_A$ is the production of machine A and $M_B$ the production of machine B.
We have that $$M_A=2M_B$$ and also that

- all defective articles from A are $\dfrac{4}{100}M_A$
- all defective articles from B are $\dfrac{2}{100}M_B$

then all defective articles are $$\dfrac{4}{100}M_A+\dfrac{2}{100}M_B=\dfrac{8}{100}M_B+\dfrac{2}{100}M_B=\dfrac{10M_B}{100}=\dfrac{M_B}{10}$$ but the total articles are $M_A+M_B=3M_B$. So the probability to get a FIRST defective article in such combination is $$p=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{M_B}{10}\right)}{3M_B}=\dfrac{1}{30}.$$

**But THEN I have a problem, how can I determine the probability to get the second defective article?**

Firstly I reasoned that if the second probability is the same as the first, then I can use binomial probability, but a careful reasoning stops me for do that because is not the same.

So my strategy is to calculate the second probability (i.e., the one that tells me the probability to get the second article defective) and then multiply this with $[1-(suchprobability)]^8$. But then I don´t know if this answer is ok, or I must calculate all possible cases of such a sequence, and my head starts to blow up.

Can somebody give me a few hints?

Comment: I would write the number of defects D in the sample of 10 as the sum of 10 indicator variables. Then D is binomial with n=10. The probability of a defect for 1 sample is (4/100)(2/3) + (2/100)(1/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be able to show that combined production has 10/300 = 3.33% defectives.

Then, the number of defectives in a sample of size $n = 10$
is $X \sim Binom(10, 10/300),$ so you can use the 
binomial formula to find $P(X = 2).$

According to my
calculations your answer should be a little smaller than 0.04.

Comment: But how do we know that 3.33% is always the same probability? If you took one ball (the first defective), then the probability changes.

Comment: I guess you are thinking about sampling without replacement (not applicable here). You are not told how many items from which the 10 are sampled. So the assumption has to be that the number of items 'produced' is huge (essentially infinite). [If it had said you have 50 from A and 25 from B mixed together and you take 10 from these 75, then you would have a more difficult problem.]

Comment: Ah! Now I see. I didn´t know that.

Comment: Good! Ideally, the point is always to learn something new.

Comment: @BruceET How did you get 10/300?

Comment: Out of every 300 articles: A produces 200 (of which we expect 8 are defective); B produces 100 (of which we expect 2 defectives). So the combined defective rate is 10 out of 300.